# How change theme of dijit.Calendar from tundra to claro?

Tags: grails, dojo

As part of a grails app, I am using a dijit.Calendar with the theme set as tundra.

In application.js

```
new dijit.Calendar({id:'calId', value: new Date()});
```

or gsp:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Calendar" id="calId" value="now" ></div>
```

and in the head section or layout.gsp file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'js',file:'/dojo-release-1.7.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css')}" />
...
<body class="tundra">
...
```

How can I set the digit.Calendar widget to use claro whilst
retaining the tundra theme for all other widgets?

Also:
Is it possible/reliable to link to both the themes in the head section and alter the body class attribute to "claro"?

Thank you

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always possible to change classes on a DOM node programmatically at any time, so yes, you could ostensibly include references to 2 themes in `head` and swap between them.

```
document.body.className = 'claro';
```

Or, with `dojo/dom-class`:

```
domClass.replace(document.body, 'claro', 'tundra'); // Adds claro and removes tundra
```

However, this is going to be an all-or-nothing one-or-the-other-at-any-given-time affair, while it sounds like you're interested in using Claro for one specific widget while still using Tundra elsewhere at the same time.  Nesting theme classes is likely to cause problems as you seem to have already discovered.

Isolating each theme class to separate parent nodes in the document might be an option depending on what you're doing, but one thing to note in particular is that in order for any popup widgets (Menus, Dialogs, Tooltips, etc.) to be themed, the theme class needs to be on `body`, since all Dijit popups are added as direct descendants of `body`.

If you're really specifically looking to mix and match Claro's Calendar with the rest of Tundra, you could create your own top-level CSS file to replace Claro's or Tundra's.  If you look at the source of either of them, you'll notice that they're both just a series of imports.  Instead, you could write your own that imports all of the components for Tundra, except for Calendar, for which you'd import Claro's.  Then you'd add both `tundra` and `claro` classes to the `body` (this wouldn't cause a problem since you're mixing and matching different components from each to create one complete theme).

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/themes.html#using-multiple-themes) suggests, `dijit/layout/ContentPane` is the way to go. Sadly, there seems to be a bug when `<body>` has one theme and some other `ContentPane` has another (the `ContentPane` gets mixed themes).
However, using multiple `ContentPane` does the trick:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>

  <script>
    require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/form/Button"]);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" class="claro">
    <button type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Claro Button</button>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" class="tundra">
    <button type="button" class="tundra" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Tundra Button</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't really need any particular widget to do this - you're simply suggesting localizing the use of each theme to a separate parent node in the DOM.  However, I'm not sure the OP has the option of changing the fact that tundra is on the body initially.

Answer (score -1):

i think you can achieve this by editing 'dojoroot/dijit/themes/tundra/Calendar.css'
as its just a normal css file u can copy the attributes from 'dojoroot/dijit/themes/claro/Calendar.css'  to 'dojoroot/dijit/themes/tundra/Calendar.css' , so u have changed the css properties of only Calendar rest remains the same.

Comment: Directly editing files within DTK packages is never recommended, mainly because it will cause headaches when it comes time to upgrade.  Keep your customizations separate from third-party libraries.  You may still need to update them in parallel, but at least you won't have to go figure out what you changed later or risk nuking them from orbit.